# Adding a UIButton to the left of a UISearchBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a UIView that contains your typical UITableView with a UISearchBar.  It seems though the Interface Builder will not let me alter the layout as I have the need to add a button to the right of the search bar.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a hook for your UIToolbar, create a property with an `IBOutlet` directive.

eg:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIToolbar * tableToolbar;//dont forget to synthesize
```

attach it to the toolbar that holds the UISearchBar, then you access the toolbar in code when your `viewDidLoad` copy the UIToolbar.items into an array, insert your button object into the array at any index you want then assign the array back to the UIToolbar.items with this function:

```
[toolbar setItems:itemArray];
```